# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

am new to reactjs, just tried to run a sample program and so for what i did is

Followed this link for environmental setup :  [tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm)

Just done all this in the tutorial, finally while i run **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import** and my os is **ubuntu**

Also a change done in above tutorial, in **index.html** `<script src = "index.js"></script>`  to `<script src = "main.js"></script>`.

Please do needful and any other ideas and any other websites to learn is appreciated.

Comment: Well you need not change anything in index.html because its correct. And if you are changing then make the same change in webpack.config.js as well where the output filename is index.js

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot install babel. Try run `npm i --save-dev babel-core babel-loader` again and see what happens